# Необходимость запятой между «что» и «как»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужна ли запятая после "что" в данном предложении?

*Что **как** через пару лет не папа сыну, а сын папе опорой станет?*

Comment: А вы точно фразу переписали? Можно конечно представить что-то такое в просторечном стиле, но в целом тут с грамматикой непонятки.

Comment: Да, да, это фраза моего собственного сочинения и принадлежит именно  персоне, которой просторечие в описанном случае в описанной обстановке к лицу))

Comment: В таком случае вы должны пояснить грамматику этой фразы. Ибо в общепринятую грамматику она не укладывается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, в данном случае мы имеем дело с сокращенной формой частицы **"а что, как"**.
Правила написания этой частицы описаны на сайте [грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_45):

> **А ЧТО, КАК**, *частица* (в начале вопросительного предложения)
>
> Выражает опасение; то же, что «а что, если», «вдруг». Не отделяется
>   запятой от последующих слов. Перед словом «как» обычно ставится
>   запятая.
>
> *Мне всё думалось: а что, как и в жизни так будет?* В. Каверин, Открытая
>   книга.
>   *А что, как его там захватили немцы?* В. Катаев, Сын полка.
>   *И вдруг в голову ударило: «А что, как беда идет?»* Б. Житков, Механик
>   Салерно.
>
> @ В художественной литературе встречаются примеры непостановки запятой
>   перед «как»:
>   *И мне приходило в голову: а что как я чего-нибудь еще не
>   знаю?* Л. Толстой, Исповедь.

Answer (score 2):

***Что как через пару лет не папа сыну, а сын папе опорой станет?***

СочетаниЯ (А) ЧТО КАК, (А) ЧТО ЕСЛИ,  встречаются в начале вопросительного предложения и имеют значение предположения, опасения.

**Запятую этом случае логично не ставить, так как пауза отсутствует.**

https://slovar.cc/rus/efremova/134166.html

**А ЧТО КАК
част. разг.-сниж.** Употребляется при выражении опасения, а также при обращении с нерешительной просьбой; что если, а ну как.

Ефремова. Новый словарь русского языка Ефремовой. 2005
﻿

Comment: Прошу прощения, а что Ваш ответ добавляет к тому, что написано в моем?

Comment: 1) Я не вижу Вашего ответа: в заданном предложении Вы ставите запятую или нет?  Её надо ставить или нет? 2) В справочнике  ее обычно ставят, но, как там сказано,   "в художественной литературе встречаются примеры непостановки запятой".  Это исключения? 3) Мой ответ взят из другого источника, там запятой нет. 4) Почему - я объясняю.

Comment: В моем ответе сказано, что в принципе ставить нужно, но можно и не ставить. Ну да ладно, не буду спорить.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите ваш вариант постановки знаков препинания (для ясности). И  ответ желательно начинать с ответа на вопрос, а потом уже объяснять его. Надеюсь на Ваше понимание: у меня не было желания "перебить" Вас, как Вы, кажется, подумали. И уж тем более у меня нет желания спорить.